# Upgrading from React 16 to 18

Tags: reactjs, react-native, dependencies, version, upgrade

Are there any problems with upgrading to React 18 directly from version 16? Or will I need to upgrade to 17 first in order to facilitate the upgrade to 18?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.